# Does it make sense Service Fabric in a single machine?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Service Fabric looks great but right now, I do not have enough demand to hire 5 machines (I think it is the minimum number of nodes of a cluster).
I was thinking to install Service Fabric SDK on a single Azure Virtual Machine.

I know that I will not have the main benefits of a service fabric application: reliability and scalability, but I will be developing in a framework that I can easily can hire more machines and to scale if it is necessary in the future without changing anything.

Right now, I have 15 microservices and I plan to add 10 more. At the present I am using IIS and deployment and maintenance is not too fast. It seems that Service Fabric could solve it, plus it would be easily scalabe

Does it make sense to use Service Fabric in a single machine? or better to keep under IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Technically it is possible, though it doesn't make much sense. [The one node cluster, runs with a special configuration and so, scale out of that cluster is not supported.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#primary-node-type---capacity-guidance) You can use a single node cluster for testing and then create another one for production use.